# display row in flutter if certain condition is true or false

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

there is a row of widgets in flutter, I want it to be visible on meeting certain condition, if the condition is true it should not be visible and if condition is false it should be visible

below is the code

```
Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          // Button send image
         Text("Text1"),
         Text("Text2"),
         Text("Text3"),
         Text("Text4"),

        ],
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: greyColor2, width: 0.5)), color: Colors.white),
    )
```

Conditions you can say for instance

```
int a==b
```

if true not visible , if false visible

How may I achieve it?

Comment: You could wrap it in a visibility widget and change it's visibility with the visible parameter and setState https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is on the assumption that the whole widget will either be visible or not which is applicable for any row also.

One way of doing it is embedding it within a `Visibility` widget
the `visible` property of the widget takes a `boolean` value

```
Visibility(
  visible: (a == b), // condition here
  child: Container(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      // Button send image
     Text("Text1"),
     Text("Text2"),
     Text("Text3"),
     Text("Text4"),

    ],
  ),
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 50.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: greyColor2, width: 0.5)), color: Colors.white),
)
)
```

Another way is to use the expression/operator
`condition ? (run this part if true) : (run this part if false)`

```
a == b ? 
Container(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      // Button send image
     Text("Text1"),
     Text("Text2"),
     Text("Text3"),
     Text("Text4"),

    ],
  ),
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 50.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: 
 greyColor2, width: 0.5)), color: Colors.white),
) : Container(), // you can also replace this with Null
```

you can use `Container()` which is an empty widget or you can simply put a `Null` so that no widget will be placed

Comment: the two way is exact for certain condition, Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can hide `children` (rows) inside a `Rows` Widget by using a combination of `if statement` and `spread operator` in dart. This is applicabe to almost all the widgets that has `children` property. The code would look something like this -

```
 child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        "Row 1",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),
      Text(
        "Row 2",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),

      //Our conditional Rows
      if (_condition) ...[
        Text(
          "Row 3",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        Text(
          "Row 4",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
      ]
    ],
  ),
```

As you can see first two rows are fixed while the last two rows can be added/removed based on the `_condition`. This conditional list will be evaluated if `_condition` is true.

Here is sample app that demonstrate this behavior, this app uses a button to toggle the `_condition`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  //Run the App Widget
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Demo App",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _condition = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Dynamic Row"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Row 1",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              Text(
                "Row 2",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              if (_condition) ...[
                Text(
                  "Row 3",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Row 4",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ]
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: FloatingActionButtonAnimator.scaling,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.red,
        animationDuration: Duration(microseconds: 500),
        child: Text(
          "Toggle",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _condition = !_condition;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the output -

[image: App Output]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
    Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Button send image
                  Text("Text1"),
                  if (a == b)
                    Text("Text2"),
                  Text("Text3"),
                  Text("Text4"),
                ],
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border:
                      Border(top: BorderSide(color: greyColor2, width: 0.5)),
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
```

You can do the same for parent Container, you just need to add the condition and based on that add widget(Container/Text).